# In sqlalchemy, how would I query a table, filtering on a translation of a column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Sometimes the search value contains random hyphens, and sometimes the column data contains random hyphens, so i'd like to do a search ignoring all hyphens.  Using wildcards on the search term only works in one direction (doesn't ignore hyphens in the table).  How would I perform this SQL using sqlalchemy?

```
select item_name, replace(item_name,'-','') as new_name 
from items 
where replace(item_name,'-','') like 'ABC%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [func](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) for generate SQL function expressions

```
from sqlalchemy import func

session.query(Item.item_name, func.replace(Item.item_name, '-', '').label('new_name')).filter(func.replace(Item.item_name, '-', '').like('ABC%')).all()
```